# Batch File > Javascript > WinSCP > Check if file exists

Tags: javascript, linux, batch-file, batch-processing, winscp

I have a batch file that will launch a .js file which, via WinSCP, checks if a file exists and returns to the batch file if it does or not.

The problem IS: It always returns not found, and I cannot figure out why. I am unsure how to use a wildcard in this scenario.

The batch file looks like this:

```
cscript /nologo file.js
if errorlevel 1 goto notfound
exit
:notfound
(another script to copy a file over)
```

Only one file can exist on the server at once. So every ten min, this batch file will run, check if there is a file, if not, copy one over.

The file.js:

```
// Configuration

// Remote file search for
var FILEPATH = "../filepath/TSS*";

// Session to connect to
var SESSION = "mysession@someplace.come";

// Path to winscp.com
var WINSCP = "c:\\program files (x86)\\winscp\\winscp.com";

var filesys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

var logfilepath = filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) + "\\" + filesys.GetTempName() + ".xml";

var p = FILEPATH.lastIndexOf('/');
var path = FILEPATH.substring(0, p);
var filename = FILEPATH.substring(p + 1);

var exec;

// run winscp to check for file existence
exec = shell.Exec("\"" + WINSCP + "\" /log=\"" + logfilepath + "\"");
exec.StdIn.Write(
"option batch abort\n" +
"open \"" + SESSION + "\"\n" +
"ls \"" + path + "\"\n" +
"exit\n");

// wait until the script finishes
while (exec.Status == 0)
{
WScript.Sleep(100);
WScript.Echo(exec.StdOut.ReadAll());
}

if (exec.ExitCode != 0)
{
WScript.Echo("Error checking for file existence");
WScript.Quit(1);
}

// look for log file
var logfile = filesys.GetFile(logfilepath);

if (logfile == null)
{
WScript.Echo("Cannot find log file");
WScript.Quit(1);
}

// parse XML log file
var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
doc.async = false;
doc.load(logfilepath);

doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", 
"xmlns:w='http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0'");

var nodes = doc.selectNodes("//w:file/w:filename[@value='" + filename + "']");

if (nodes.length > 0)
{
WScript.Echo("File found");
// signalize file existence to calling process;
// you can also continue with processing (e.g. downloading the file)
// directly from the script here
WScript.Quit(0);
}
else
{
WScript.Echo("File not found");
WScript.Quit(1);
}
```

On line 4 it says:

```
var FILEPATH = "../filepath/TSS*";
```

That star is what is giving me issues, i think. I need to look for a file which STARTS WITH TSS, but will have a time stamp tacked on the end. So i need to just use a wildcard after TSS.

So what i need help with is: Making this process return true if any file exists with TSS*

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
var nodes = doc.selectNodes("//w:file/w:filename[starts-with(@value, 'TSS')]");
```

This code seems to not work. If this code worked, it seems like it would solve all my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct xpath expression in `var nodes...` line.
Try something like this:

```
doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath"); //added in edit
var nodes = doc.selectNodes("//w:file/w:filename[starts-with(@value, '" + filename + "')]");
```

and delete asterisk from `FILEPATH`.

Note: first line is required in order to use `XPath` as the query language, not default (and old) `XSLPattern` which doesn't support methods such as `starts-with` or `contains`.

[*SelectionLanguage Property* (MDSN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Close! I am getting an error saying unknown method on that line you modified with "starts-with".

Comment: I have tried every possible combination i could think of. I am still not getting it to work. Is there a way to just search for TSS in the xml file?

Comment: `var nodes = doc.selectNodes("//w:file/w:filename[starts-with(@value, 'TSA')]");` Should work, no?

Comment: If I didn't make any mistakes then yes. I have no idea what is causing  error now.

Comment: @user2241406 you can try to replace `starts-with` by `contains`.

Comment: `var nodes = doc.selectNodes("//w:file/w:filename[contains (@value, '" + filename + "')]");` returns this error: `msxm13.dll: Unknow method. //w:file/w:filename[-->contains(@<--value,'TSS')]`

Comment: Try adding `doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");` line before defining `nodes`

Comment: OMG!!!!!!! It worked. Thank you. I have been looking for this fix since 10 AM this morning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`stat` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_stat). You can even inline the WinSCP script into the batch file:

```
@echo off

set REMOTE_PATH=/home/user/test.txt
winscp.com /command ^
    "option batch abort" ^
    "open mysession" ^ 
    "stat %REMOTE_PATH%" ^ 
    "exit"

if errorlevel 1 goto error

echo File %REMOTE_PATH% exists
rem Do something
exit 0

:error
echo Error or file %REMOTE_PATH% not exists
exit 1
```

---

An alternative is using the [`Session.FileExists`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_fileexists) from [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

---

For further details, see the WinSCP article [Checking file existence](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence).

Comment: It would indeed make my life easier, under the assumption I even know how to code more than hello world.